# How to solve my terminal Vscode cannot work and said "Shell Integration failed to activate"

Tags: php, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, laragon

[image: all command cannot working]

[image: terminal]

how to solve this problem?

i just want to use my terminal but suddenly this is happening

> "Shell Integration failed to activate"